# find exact string match in C++

Tags: c++, string, match

Here is the code I used to detect the string in a line from a txt file:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file( "C:\\log.txt" );

    std::string line;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        while( std::getline( file, line ) )   
        {
            int found = -1;
            if((found = line.find("GetSA"))>-1)
                std::cout<<"We found GetSA."<<std::endl;
            else if ((found = line.find("GetVol"))>-1)
                std::cout<<"We found GetVol."<<std::endl;
            else if ((found = line.find("GetSphereSAandVol"))>-1)
                std::cout<<"We found GetSphereSAandVol."<<std::endl;
            else
                std::cout<<"We found nothing!"<<std::endl;

        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

And here is my log file:

```
GetSA (3.000000)

GetVol (3.000000)

GetSphereSAandVol (3.000000)

GetVol (3.000000)

GetSphereSAandVol (3.000000)

GetSA (3.00000)
```

The error is, the program will not go to find "GetSphereSAandVol", because it stops at "GetSA". Obviously, the program thinks "GetSphereSAandVol" contains "GetSA", so it will execute:

```
if(found = line.find("GetSA"))
    std::cout<<"We found GetSA."<<std::endl;
```

which is not exactly what I want, because I am expecting the program to execute:

```
else if (found = line.find("GetSphereSAandVol"))
    std::cout<<"We found GetSphereSAandVol."<<std::endl;
```

So, anyway I can avoid this? to get what I really want? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The outer while loop serves no purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand how `find` works. Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

The conditionals should go like this:

```
if ((found = line.find("xyz")) != line.npos) { /* found "xyz" */ }
```

---

I would write your entire program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) { std::cout << "Bad invocation\n"; return 0; }

    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    if (!infile) { std::cout << "Bad filename '" << argv[1] << "'\n"; return 0; }

    for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
    {
        int pos;

        if ((pos = line.find("abc")) != line.npos)
        {
            std::cout << "Found line 'abc'\n";
            continue;
        }

        if ((pos = line.find("xyz")) != line.npos)
        {
            std::cout << "Found line 'xyz'\n";
            continue;
        }

        // ...

        std::cout << "Line '" << line << "' did not match anything.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two errors, one you asked about and one you didn't.

Your if statements are wrong. You misunderstand how `string::find` works. This is the correct way

```
        if ((found = line.find("GetSA")) != string::npos)
           ...
        else if ((found = line.find("GetVol")) != string::npos)
           ...
        etc.
```

If `string::find` does not find what it's looking for it returns a special value `string::npos`. This is what your if conditions should test for.

Second error, lose the `while (!file.eof())` loop, it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `string::find` function returns `string::npos` if not found.  Otherwise it returns an index.  You are assuming it returns a boolean and are testing accordingly.  That will not work, because `string::npos` evaluates to a boolean truth (non-zero).   Also, if the substring is at index zero, that will not pass.

You must instead do this:

```
if( std::string::npos != (found = line.find("GetSA")) )
   // etc...
```

Personally, I don't like the style of setting a value and testing in this way, but that's up to you.  I might do this instead with a simple helper function:

```
bool FindSubString( std::string& str, const char *substr, int& pos )
{
    pos = str.find(substr);
    return pos != std::string::npos;
}
```

Then:

```
if( FindSubString( line, "GetSA", found ) )
    // etc...
```

But in your case, you're not even using the `found` variable.  So you can ignore what I've said about style and just do:

```
if( std::string::npos != line.find("GetSA") )
    // etc...
```