# matching exact substring using std::regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to make a regex to match an exact substring so that I can remove it from a string.

```
std::string str = "{abc}slkj skdjv{abc}nei slkjdf";
std::regex reg("{abc}");
str = std::regex_replace(str, reg, "");
```

I tried this regex on [Regexr](http://regexr.com) and it works (it matches the {abc} like I want it to). However, the above code seems to run into an infinite loop.

The reason I want to use a regex is because I am also using it to remove other things that aren't just string matching, so I am not looking for straight string operations like the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020526/find-exact-string-match-in-c).

What should the regex string actually be to match that specific string?

Comment: How on earth does failing to find a regex match make your code run in an infinite loop?

Comment: That's a good question that I don't have the answer to. It gets stuck in regex_replace. :|

Comment: `{abc}` is invalid regex, since `{}` is meant to be used for repetition counts. For instance, `a{1,3}` matches 1-3 `a` characters. The input is malformed, it's not just failing to find a match. My best guess would be that it's trying to find repeats of the empty string and thus never progressing in its search, but I'm in no way sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to actually match `{abc}`, you need to use the regex `\{abc\}`. `{}` are special tokens in regex, and so they must be escaped.

Comment: And don't forget, the backslashes must themselves be escaped within the string literal, unless you use raw string literals.

Comment: I had originally tried \{abc\} but Xcode was telling me that \} was an invalid escape sequence. The escaping of the backslashes themselves was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @mxdg Nah, don't escape the backslashes, use raw string literals, assuming your compiler supports it - `std::regex reg(R"(\{abc\})");`